# MLE of Integer Valued Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, arithmetic, statistical-inference

If Z is a normal random variable on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with parameters $(\mu,\Sigma)$ and we know that $\mu\in \mathbb{Z}^d$ and $\Sigma \in \mathbb{Z}^{d+}$; then how can we solve this MLE problem for the MLES of $\mu$ and $\Sigma$?

Answer (score 1):

Solve this as an integer constrained nonlinear programming (optimization) problem.  Maximize likelihood (or minimize log likelihood or whatever) subject to the constraints that mu and sigma^2 are integers, and sigma^2 is positive.  Use mixed integer nonlinear optimization software to do so (technically, all your variables are integer, so it's not really mixed, nevertheless software for mixed will work).  You could use KNITRO for finding a local optimum, or use BARON to try to find a global optimum.  Depending on the size and difficulty of the problem, there is no guarantee that BARON will find the global optimum (but if it tells you it has, you can trust it).  There are probably other nonlinear optimizers as well which can handle integer variables.  Unless you use a global optimizer, there is no guarantee you will be finding the global optimum, which is what you really want.  Even if you have found a global optimum, for instance in BARON, I don't think you are able to get a guarantee that there aren't other points which achieve the same global optimum objective value, which in the case of MLE, would be very relevant to know.

One thing you could try is using YALMIP (free) under MATLAB. Without having to acquire even a trial license to KNITRO or BARON, you can use YALMIP"s own BMIBNB global branch and bound optimizer, which in principle will try to do the same thing as BARON, but is not as sophisticated, so its chances of success aren't as good, and chances of success may depend on the quality of Linear Programming and continuous variable local nonlinear optimizer available to solve subproblems).

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution, but I expect it can be done by hand in a simple way as I've seen this problem on an old comprehensive exam.

Comment: I suppose that depends on the size of the problem and the data. If there's a sample closed form solution, I'd like to see it.  Based on the data, you can bound the optimal values of mu and sigma^2, and if those bounds are tight enough, you can use brute force enumeration to find the combination of mu and sigma^2 having maximum likelihood.  The "brute force" approach can go South in a hurry though, big time.

Comment: The "brute force" approach will blow up geometrically as d increases, so becomes unviable unless the bounds on mu and sigma^2 are tight per dimension. What value(s) of d do you have in mind?

Comment: Actually, your problem statement is a little confusing. You say the data is in d dimensions, but you talk about mu and sigma^2 as if they're scalars (no superscript d on Z), as opposed to vectors.  And if vectors, are you assuming the covariance matrix is diagonal, so that you are not estimating off-diagonal entries?

Comment: I suppose you could have a problem in which diagonal entries are integer and off-diagonal are continuous (or could do with integer constraints on all elements of covariance) . If you're estimating the full covariance matrix, you'll need a semidefinite constraint. That puts BARON out. To do that in KNITRO, you'd have to put in a min(eig(covariance matrix)) >= 0 constraint, which is quite doable.

Comment: I clarified my notation, but I remember reading an article recently which derived a closed form solution in a few lines for the case where $d=1$, so I imagine it should be readily computable by hand.

Comment: Yes, if d = 1, based on the data, you can bound possible values of mu and sigma^2,, then solve by brute force enumeration.  That will blow up big time as d increases, the more so as you've now clarified that you are estimating an entire integer covariance matrix.  The best approach I can think of to solve this is KNITRO, where you add the min(eig(covariance) >= 0 constraint to enforce it being psd. But you will only get a local optimum, which may not be globally optimum.  You may need to try alternate starting values for your variables in an attempt to do better.

Comment: Don't confuse an exam problem for d = 1, and perhaps tight spread of data which provides tight bounds on mu and sigma^2, with a d = 3 or higher say, and maybe not super tight data.  That will blow up like a proverbial son of a bitch by brute force approach.

Comment: There is a similar but easier problem, posed as Student Puzzle Corner  8 on p. 15 in http://bulletin.imstat.org/wp-content/uploads/Bulletin44_2.pdf and solved on p. 17 of http://bulletin.imstat.org/wp-content/uploads/Bulletin44_3.pdf . That's only 1D, and only mu, not sigma^2 is integer constrained. Optimal solution in that case is to round continuous MLE to nearest integer, then MLS for sigma^2 is based on that mu. Your problem is much more difficult.

Comment: But i think that should get you the mu vector (component at a time). Then you need to solve for the covariance matrix.entries.